# MySQL 1054 error on multiple nested level queries

Tags: mysql, nested, subquery

I have an issue on the follow query on MySQL 5.6:

```
select 
(c.datefield) as dfield,
(select 
    count(t1.C_URI)
    from 
        (select C_URI,MAX(C_updated) dataOpen from  workitem wi where C_status<>'closed' and date(C_updated)<=c.datefield group by C_URI) t1
    left outer join
        (select C_URI,MAX(C_updated) dataClosed from  workitem wi where C_status='closed' and date(C_updated)<=c.datefield group by C_URI) t2   
    on 
        t1.C_URI=t2.C_URI
    where 
        t1.dataOpen> ifnull(t2.dataClosed,0)
) as tot
from 
    calendar c 
left join 
    workitem 
on 
    date(datefield)=date(C_updated)
where
    datefield between ('2014-10-01') and ('2014-10-20')
group by 
    datefield;
```

The problem is that MySQL can not recognise the `date(C_updated)<=c.datefield` raising an error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.datefield' in 'where clause'    0.000 sec
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance...!

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `c.datefield` and not `calendar.datefield`, like it says in the error message? Once you assign an alias to a table, you can't use the full name of the table.

Comment: Edited, it was an error on cut&paste, thank you